# c++: What is a good refactor for a duplicate member field in the subclass of a multiply-inherited class?

Tags: c++, refactoring, multiple-inheritance

Title edits that reflect a better summary of the question are welcome.

I'd like to refactor these three classes somehow to remove the duplicate field represented in `class C` (see hierarchy). I thought about pulling the field up into a parent class, but the issue is that A and B are not similar enough to be considered "is-a", C is considered *both*, and it is literally only *one* member field so creating a class just to hold ONE THING seems a bit overkill.

Hierarchy:

```
(abstract data type)
class A : public O {
    public:
    //...
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetName() const;
    void SetName(std::string name);
    //...
    protected:
    //...
    std::string _name;
    //...
};

//Methods and fields shown here represent the exact same representative data as in A but the classes are so dissimilar as to not be considered "is-a" relationship.
(abstract data type)
class B {
    public:
    //...
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetName() const;
    void SetName(std::string name);
    //...
    protected:
    //...
    std::string _name;
    //...
};

(concrete)
class C : public A, public B {
    public:
    //...
    C(/*..Other parameters..*/, std::string name, /*....*/)
    : A(name, /*...*/), B(name, /*...*/) {
        /*...*/
    }
    //...
    private:
    //...        
};
```

Comment: This seems perfectly acceptable, you're combining two classes that are not linked by parents to which you need to add new data/methods. Besides, they're both abstract so how else could you do it?

Comment: If you do not want to make a separate class for only one member then I think this design is already good. Over-optimizing might not be a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this question and answers: [Get rid of ugly if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786358/get-rid-of-ugly-if-statements) clearly shows that, as @Andre mentioned, your current code is perfectly acceptable and trying to "fix" it may cause same pain and mind blow.

Leave it AS-IS, it's good.

Answer (score 1):

You can either leave it as-is, as said previously or you can consider using [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) for class C like:

```
class C : public A
{
public:
    // ...
    // The GetName and SetName methods are inherited from A.

private:
    B* b;
};
```

or

```
class C
{
public:
    // ...

    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetName() const;
    void SetName(std::string name);

private:
    A* a;
    B* b;
};
```

Comment: This is a better choice if there are no other classes that also want names.

Comment: I'm inclined to agreeing with user315052, even though this is the only class that inherits from both A and B, there are other classes that inherit just from A or just from B that need names.

Answer (score 0):

Since `C` is passing in the same `name` parameter to both `A` and `B`, you might be able to get what you want with virtual inheritance. `V` below is defined to be a common base class for `A`, `B`, and `C`, but with virtual inheritance, they all share the same instance.

```
class V {
    public:
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetName() const;
    void SetName(std::string name);
    protected:
    std::string _name;
    V () {}
    V (std::string n) : _name(n) {}
    ~V () {}
};

class A : virtual public V, public O {
    //...
};

class B : virtual public V {
    //...
};

class C : virtual public V, public A, public B {
    public:
    C (/*...otherargs,*/std::string name/*,moreargs...*/)
        : V(name), A(/*...*/), B(/*...*/) {
        //...
    }
    //...
};
```